# Logger is writing to file out of order

Tags: c#, logging, thread-safety, file-writing

I have a logging system which is composed of two static classes. The first class does a simple check of a bool to determine if it should log to a file, and then creates a new Task which calls another static class's method to actually write to a file.

This has worked except when I open up the log file, the lines appear to be written out of order for a lot of them. I'm guessing this is related to the `Task`.

My main goal is to not block the GUI thread while logging and for it to be quick.

Here's the relative code in my first class:

```
private static readonly string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location) + "\\" + "AppLog" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-M-yyyy--HH-mm-ss") + ".txt";
public static bool doWrite= true; //on by default

public static void Log(string msgToLog)
{
    if (!doWriteToFile)
    {
        return;
    }

    Task.Run(() => { LogMessage(msgToLog); } );
}

private static void LogMessage(string msgToLog)
{
    FileWriter.WriteToFileThreadSafe(exePath, msgToLog);
}
```

And here's my `FileWriter` class:

```
public static class FileWriter
{
    private static readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim ReadWriteLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public static void WriteToFileThreadSafe(string filePath, string text)
    {
        // Set Status to Locked
        ReadWriteLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            // Append text to the file
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filePath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(text);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Release lock
            ReadWriteLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

More info:

There are certain functions that, when called, the user wants logged no matter what. Sometimes these functions are called thousands of times in a few seconds.

Comment: could you not wait until a certain point in time (future) to write the logged file? If so then storing the log message and time would allow you to write the log message always in the correct order regardless of anything

Comment: Anyway, since it is IO and you are locking the Streamwriter the moment it unlocks it might be released to a different Task.

Comment: You only  need to create the lock once.  You are constantly recreating the lock with :  new ReaderWriterLockSlim() which is defeating the purpose.

Comment: @Democrats The users like to check the log at random points while running the app.

Comment: ok, another solution would be to add the log messages with the entry time and sort them once you have a chance (possibly the moment when a user opens the log file)

Comment: Depends on your design really. But make sure to do a lot of stress testing.

Answer (score 0):

Include ThreadId Field in your logging template. If there's a user interface where your user is checking the logs then you can highlight the logs with different formatting for each ThreadId to identify when the thread was doing it's work while main thread was suspended.